# SSIS Teradata - Unable to parse volatile table creation

Tags: ssis, oledb, teradata

I have 3 parts to a teradata query

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE ...
SELECT QUERY -- Using the volatile table
DROP TABLE -- Volatile table
```

Works fine in Teradata SQL assistant,

Throws me an error **Data definition not valid unless solitary** in SSIS Data Flow task when I execute this using `SQL command using variable`

Any way to resolve this issue? Other than creating a gtt table in Teradata space and using it.

Comment: Could you post the the full version of the queries?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that in a single statement with Teradata. This is the same as the ever popular _only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL statement_. You'll need to use the global temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a SELECT QUERY, skipping a table. Either way you'll be working with a resultset.